# Ncurses program exits when terminal resized

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

When i resize my terminal window, the below program exits. Why and how can stop it?

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
    initscr ();

    printw ("Some text\n");
    refresh ();

    sleep (100);
    endwin ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=ncurses+resize

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738803/resize-terminal-and-scrolling-problem-with-ncurses)

When terminal has resized, the `SIGWINCH` signal raises and program exits.

Here is the solution:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main () {
    initscr ();

    signal (SIGWINCH, NULL);

    printw ("Some text\n");
    refresh ();

    sleep (100);
    endwin ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But for an ncurses program, you will need to actually handle the signal in order to adapt your layout to the new terminal size.

Comment: It's written in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738803/resize-terminal-and-scrolling-problem-with-ncurses)

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the SIGWINCH signal :

```
#include <signal.h>

/* resizer handler, called when the user resizes the window */
void resizeHandler(int sig) {
    // update layout, do stuff...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    signal(SIGWINCH, resizeHandler);

    // play with ncurses
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I would only call async-signal-safe functions from a signal handler. Read `signal(7)` man page. The usual way is to only set a `volatile sigatomic_t` flag in the signal handler, and to test that flag elsewhere...