# Segmentation fault & core dumped with changing window size

Tags: c, malloc, free, ncurses

I make some program that using ncurses to using window(?).

there is strange problem!! (I use PUTTY)

if we change window size, deleteTree() is not working well.
But if we maintain window size, deleteTree() is working well!!

the function of deleteTree() is

```
MAX_CHILD = 100
enum DAY {MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN};
enum TREE_TYPE {HEADER,DAY,PLACE,ROOM};
typedef struct _tree {
    enum TREE_TYPE type;
    union _info info;
    struct _tree* link[MAX_CHILD];
} tree;

typedef tree* tNode;
tNode tRoot;


void deleteTree(tNode* twalk)
{
    int i;
    if (*twalk == NULL)
        return;
    for (i=0;i < MAX_CHILD;i++)
    {
        if ((*twalk)->link[i] != NULL){
            deleteTree(&(*twalk)->link[i]);
            (*twalk)->link[i] = NULL;
        }else break;
    }
    free(*twalk);
    *twalk = NULL;

}
```

and

```
void deleteTree(tNode twalk)
{
    int i;
    if (twalk == NULL)
        return;
    for (i=0;twalk->link[i]!=NULL;i++)
    {
        deleteTree(twalk->link[i]);
        free(twalk->link[i]);
        twalk->link[i] = NULL;
    }
    if (twalk == tRoot)
    {
        if (twalk != NULL) 
            free(twalk);
        tRoot = NULL;
    }

}
```

both of them are not working if window size are changed. the error message is segmentation falut(core dumped).

I think this error means when change window size makes change location of memory.
how to solve this problem...?

Comment: Need more context.  How does the tree get built?  How does it related to ncurses?

Comment: This problem could be in another part of your code.  For example if you don't allocate link to zero for all 100 elements when you create each node you would get a segmentation fault when you run this code (or other undefined results.)

Comment: The both seem correct. (the typedeffed pointer could be considered harmful). What is the meaning of the `type` and `info` struct members? (these *could* be used to simulate polymorphism ...)

Comment: BTW: the crash *could* be caused by the *constructor* function not initializing all `link[]` values to NULL (or another sane value).

Comment: Use a debugger to to produce a stack trace and the state of the variables at the moment of crash.

Comment: I use gdb to find where error occurs, read core (gdb -c=core a.out) that shows deleteTree has error. `for (i ~ )`

Comment: abnormality, if I do not change window size, program working well!!

Comment: How are you catching SIGWINCH?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450682/ncurses-program-exits-when-terminal-resized

Comment: @user3503219 - crashing on the for statement suggests (as both wildplasser and I pointed out) that you have to initialize the entire array to 0.  Also you don't check for `> MAX_CHILD` so maybe you have a node with 100 sub-elements and no room for the null in the array?